# How to use log4php on PHP 8.2?

Tags: php, log4php

log4php generates a `Deprecated: fwrite(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($data) of type string is deprecated in D:\inc\log4php\appenders\LoggerAppenderFile.php on line 137`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
        <param name="file" value="test.log" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender_ref ref="default" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and initialization

```
require ROOT . "/inc/log4php/Logger.php";
Logger::configure( ROOT . 'log-config.xml' );
$logger = Logger::getLogger( 'main' );
define( 'LOG', $logger );
LOG->debug( 'utils.php' );
```

What would be the proper way to start the log4php logger? I copied the settings from the documentation.

Comment: If it's https://github.com/apache/logging-log4php, it's been archived and no longer supported. You probably won't be able to get it to work with PHP 8.2 without a bunch of rewriting.

Comment: you could try to create your own layout, the child class of `LoggerLayoutSimple` (or `LoggerLayout` and defining the `format` method too), overriding the `getFooter` and `getHeader` methods so these do not return null but empty string instead for example, and then `LOG->setLayout(new MyLoggerLayout());`

Comment: In any case, this rather looks like a bug report, which would be misplaced here.

Answer (score 2):

The official [log4php](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4php) project is now old and inactive, but there exists  [a fork](https://github.com/armando-basile/logging-log4php) that added PHP 8 compatibility (as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4php/compare/master...armando-basile:logging-log4php:master)):

> add support for php > 8.0 (fwrite null)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only message you're getting, one option is to **ignore the message, for now**. Don't ignore it forever, but don't panic right now.

A deprecation notice is *not an error*; it is a message warning you that *a future version of PHP* will throw an error on that piece of code. Due to PHP's compatibility policy, that will be PHP 9.0 at the earliest. The entire purpose of such messages is to give you time to fix them.

From the context you've given, the message is not about how you're calling the library, it's about how the library is handling some situation. So there are two possibilities:

- Someone is maintaining the library, or someone is willing to take it over (maybe you?). They have until PHP 9.0 comes out to change the code before it becomes an error.
- Nobody is maintaining the library (including you). You will need to find a different library, or rewrite your code not to depend on it - but you have until you want to run on PHP 9.0 to do so.

Note that your application might treat this notice as though it as an error, by setting a custom "error handler" - some frameworks do this by default on development mode. Consider whether you think that is a useful configuration, and whether fixing messages like this as early as possible is the right priority for your time.

Comment: I'm not panicking, I don't want to include third party software containing even more errors than the one I write. So I will have to write my own logger.

Answer (score -1):

After spending some time with log4php and various forks I came to the conclusion to go wit [monolog](https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/) instead despite its [performance](https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-php-logging-frameworks-which-is-fastest-and-most-reliable-2/)

Thanks for the useful comments